# Groovy coercing List to Map doesn't throw ClassCastException or what is ArrayList1_groovyProxy?

Tags: groovy, types, casting

I was writing code where I tried to cast an Object to a Map.

```
Map a = object as Map
```

I could alternatively use

```
Map a = (Map) object
```

and the whole question would be irrelevant as this throws a `ClassCastException` if the object is of type List, but by using the former I encountered an interesting thing.
If the object is a List, i.e. `object = []`, groovy type coercion will behave different from what I expected.

My expectation was to get a `ClassCastException`, but instead I got a resulting object. But this object seems odd. It is an instance of List and an instance of Map and using `.toString()` on it resulted in the output of a List, not a Map (`[a,b]`). Also it is not possible to set a value on the map with `a['c'] = 'c'`. This results in a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`.

```
Map a = ['a', 'b'] as Map

println(a)
println(a instanceof List)
println(a instanceof Map)
println(a.getClass())
```

results in the following output:

```
[a, b]
true
true
class ArrayList1_groovyProxy
```

I tried to google to find out what this `ArrayList1_groovyProxy` is, but couldn't find anything.

It still doesn't make sense to me, that the coercion returns an object that obviously is not really what it should be and also seems kind of broken, instead of just throwing a `ClassCastException`.

Can anyone explain to me the reasoning behind that behavior instead of throwing the exception and explain the use of `ArrayList1_groovyProxy`? Or is this just a bug in groovy?

Comment: `['a', 'b']` is a `List`. If you want a map, then define `def map = ['1': 'one', '2': 'two']`. Now try to `assert map instanceof Map`

Comment: I know that `['a', 'b']` is a List. That was not the point. The questions was why `['a', 'b'] as Map` doesn't throw a ClassCastException like `(Map) ['a', 'b']` does. Because it seems that the resulting object is pretty unusable.

Comment: Not sure, but you are forcing it by saying `as Map` while defining. You can see the exception with `Map a = ['a', 'b']`

Comment: That's true, but in my real useCase I don't know yet whether I get a list or something else. So to use `@CompileStatic` I need to do the coercion. That's why this even occurred here. Otherwise you're totally right that `Map a = object` would be enough.

I'm wondering about returning a seemingly broken object instead of throwing an exception, if this seems to be an exceptional state.

Comment: Then, I may suggest just use `def variable`. instead of static type. While using use `if (variable instanceof Map) {} else if (variable instanceof List) {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `as` [operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_coercion_operator) calls the `asType` method with the provided type as the argument to the method.

You can see the default implementation for `asType` in [`DefaultGroovyMethods`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java).

Since `Map` is an interface, it will eventually call `ProxyGenerator.INSTANCE.instantiateDelegate(interfaces, obj)`, which returns a dynamic proxy that implements `Map`.

```
/**
 * Converts a given object to a type. This method is used through
 * the "as" operator and is overloadable as any other operator.
 *
 * @param obj  the object to convert
 * @param type the goal type
 * @return the resulting object
 * @since 1.0
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T asType(Object obj, Class<T> type) {
    if (String.class == type) {
        return (T) InvokerHelper.toString(obj);
    }

    // fall back to cast
    try {
        return (T) DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(obj, type);
    }
    catch (GroovyCastException e) {
        MetaClass mc = InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(obj);
        if (mc instanceof ExpandoMetaClass) {
            ExpandoMetaClass emc = (ExpandoMetaClass) mc;
            Object mixedIn = emc.castToMixedType(obj, type);
            if (mixedIn != null)
                return (T) mixedIn;
        }
        if (type.isInterface()) {
            try {
                List<Class> interfaces = new ArrayList<Class>();
                interfaces.add(type);
                return (T) ProxyGenerator.INSTANCE.instantiateDelegate(interfaces, obj);
            } catch (GroovyRuntimeException cause) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
        throw e;
    }
```

As to why Groovy goes to such great lengths to coerce types--it's basically the nature of Groovy: making Java coding easier. You can construct an object by [passing a `Map` to its constructor](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_initializing_beans_with_named_parameters_and_the_default_constructor), or even [coerce a `Map` instance to a particular type](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-lists-and-maps-as.html); so why not let every object be coerced back into a `Map` via the `as` operator?

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains the proxy class. 
Still doesn't explain why it would even return that, if it then doesn't support the usual Map operations. I would agree that it is ok to coerce everything back to a map if a map can be used in constructors to create everything, but wouldn't the expectation then be to just return something like object.properties?